# How to permanently delete node?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have deleted node with following commands:

```
rabbitmqctl -n mynode@hostname stop_app
rabbitmqctl stop_app;
rabbitmqctl -n mynode@hostname reset
rabbitmqctl start_app;
```

And when I check in cluster, node is not there anymore:

```
rabbitmqctl cluster_status
```

Problem is that when I check status of reseted node, node is still there:

```
rabbitmqctl -n mynode@G2dev2 status
```

So my question is how to delete node permanently?

No info about that on man page: https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html

Thank you

Comment: this is command: rabbitmqctl -n mynode@hostname shutdown

Comment: should I put this as answer or delete question?

Comment: So I tested this `rabbitmqctl stop_app && rabbitmqctl reset && rabbitmqctl start_app` and it was enough for me.. checked cluster status on other nodes and it was gone. Using rabbit 3.7.3 Erlang 20.2.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node` command to remove a node from cluster.

Answer (score 8):

You first must stop the node you wish to remove:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@node3 stop_app
```

Then from one of the other nodes you can then use the forget_cluster_node command:

```
rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@node3
```

Here are the details about that command:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#forget_cluster_node